# Insert a div at a particular position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page with lots of divs, like a form filling page (not statically fixed but generated dynamically).

Here I need to create a new div and place it in a particular [x,y] position which is also not fixed but will get dynamically while rendering.

So my question is how to place a newly created div in a particular [x,y] position using javascript/jquery?

I am trying like this but the div is not appearing:

```
const showFormFieldErrorMessage = function (data, message) {
    const errorMsg = message || 'This field is required.';
    const errorElem = document.createElement('div');
    errorElem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    errorElem.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    errorElem.style.top = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posy) ? data.position.posy : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.style.left = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posx) ? data.position.posx : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.zIndex = 900;
};
```

NOTE: The parameter data is where I get the position details in runtime.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you want to add your div inside some container's div or directly on document's body?

Comment: You need to add your div inside another/container div or directly on the document `body` - just creating a div and giving it some properties doesn't add it to the DOM

Comment: I want to add it inside another container parent div

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add your newly created div to document's body following can be used:

```
const showFormFieldErrorMessage = function (data, message) {
    const errorMsg = message || 'This field is required.';
    const errorElem = document.createElement('div');
    errorElem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    errorElem.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    errorElem.style.top = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posy) ? data.position.posy : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.style.left = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posx) ? data.position.posx : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.style.position = 'absolute';
    errorElem.zIndex = 900;

    document.body.appendChild(errorElem);
};
```

You can add new element to document's body using:

```
document.body.appendChild(errorElem);
```

Note: Make sure to make the position 'absolute' of your `errorElem` otherwise the top and left properties won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas are as follows:

1. Your div needs to be positioned first i.e set the `style.position` property of the element.
2. Set the `style.top`, `style.left` properties of the element to place the element on a specific coordinate.

Here is the working example:

```js
function addToCoordinates() {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    var x_pos = '100px', y_pos = '100px';

    div1.id = 'div1';
    div1.style.height = "200px";
    div1.style.width = "200px";
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "#1abc9c";
    div1.style.position = "absolute";
    div1.style.left = x_pos;
    div1.style.top = y_pos;

    document.body.appendChild(div1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addToCoordinates()">Add div on a particular position</button>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  Maybe add some explanation?  Would help others.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. In order to use css styles for `top` and `left`, you need to have the element be positioned.  I'm going with `relative`, but you can choose any.  To quote the MDN documentation for `top`...

> The top CSS property participates in specifying the vertical position of a positioned element. It has no effect on non-positioned elements. (Source: [**MDN Web Docs: top**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top).)

2. To append the element to the body, you can use [**`document.body.appendChild()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) for JavaScript and [**`append()`**](https://api.jquery.com/append/) for jQuery (since your question is tagged both JavaScript and jQuery).

***JavaScript Demo***

```js
const showFormFieldErrorMessage = function (data, message) {
    const errorMsg = message || 'This field is required.';
    const errorElem = document.createElement('div');
    errorElem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    errorElem.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    errorElem.style.position = "relative";
    errorElem.style.top = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posy) ? data.position.posy : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.style.left = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posx) ? data.position.posx : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.zIndex = 900;
    document.body.appendChild(errorElem);
};

showFormFieldErrorMessage({position:{posx:150, posy:150}}, "hello, I'm a message!");
```

```html
<html><head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

***jQuery Demo***

```js
const showFormFieldErrorMessage = function (data, message) {
    const errorMsg = message || 'This field is required.';
    const errorElem = document.createElement('div');
    errorElem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    errorElem.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    errorElem.style.position = "relative";
    errorElem.style.top = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posy) ? data.position.posy : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.style.left = `${(data && data.position && data.position.posx) ? data.position.posx : '0'}px`;
    errorElem.zIndex = 900;
    $(document.body).append(errorElem);
};

showFormFieldErrorMessage({position:{posx:150, posy:150}}, "hello, I'm a message!");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```